# Failing to prove parametric equations of Witch of Agnesi

Tags: geometry, algebraic-curves

**Edit: I got it right. Nevermind this question. But it may as well be a read for people who cant get this parametrization.**

Thanks in advance for reading my question. I am missing something and need some help in finding what I have done wrong. Also, if I am not able to solve this, I'd appreciate any explanations not involving triangle similarity, using functions mostly. And bear with me, English is not my first language :).

I am supposed to prove that a parametric representation of a Witch of Agnesi, which is given by $$\ \sigma(\theta)=(2\alpha \cot (\theta),2\alpha \sin^2(\theta))\ \ \ ,\ \ \  t\in (0,\pi)$$

**The problem parameters:**

[Problem depiction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ep6i.png)

Circle equation: $\gamma:\ \  x^2+(y-a)^2=a^2$

Line equation: $r:\ \  y=2\alpha$

**The attempt of solution**:

$$S=(x_1,y_1)\\Q=(x_2,y_2)\\P=(x_3,y_3)$$
As ***P*** as the same x coordinate as ***Q*** and the same y coordinate as ***S***, we can write $P=(x_2,y_1)$
As $\cot(\theta)=\Large\frac{x_2}{2a}$$,\ x_2=2a\cot(\theta)$

The line $\overline{\rm OQ}$ is defined by $y=\Large\frac{x_2}{2a}\normalsize x\rightarrow x=\Large \frac{y}{\tan(\theta)}$

Plugging this into the circle equation, I get $(\Large \frac{y}{\tan(\theta)}\normalsize)^2+(y-a)^2=a^2$, which gives the solution $\large y=2\alpha \sin^2(\theta)$, which is clearly <s>wrong</s> right. What am I missing?

Comment: I was solving for x instead of y. That's what was wrong. Oh well.